# Размер картинки и libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть картинка (help_15.jpg), размер соответствует разрешению экрана,(если взять картинку большего размера, то она так и выглядит большой съезжая за края экрана).

На устройствах с большим разрешение экрана картинка выглядит меньше.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы картинка растягивалась на весь экран при любом разрешении или как изначально картинку поставить высокого разрешения, чтобы масштабировалась под экран. (background это отдельная текстура).

Спасибо.

```
public class ScreenTest extends ScreenAdapter 
{
    public ScreenTest() 
    {
        float pad = Main.screen_width * 0.01f;
        Table outerTable = new  Table().top().background(newTextureRegionDrawable(Main.background)).padTop(pad). padBottom(pad * 5);
        outerTable.row().padTop(pad*5).colspan(2);

        Imagehelp_15=newImage(newTextureRegion(newTexture(Gdx.files.internal("help_15.jpg"))));
        Container containerHelp15 = new Container(help_15).align(Align.center);
        outerTable.add(containerHelp15);
        outerTable.row().padTop(pad*0).colspan(1);

        @Override 
        public void render(float delta)
        {
            Main.stage.act();
            Main.stage.draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: пробовали Gdx.graphics.getWidth() присваивать ширине картинки и так же с высотой?